# Why "exit" is needed after wp_redirect?

Tags: wp-redirect

This is probably a PHP question, but since I encountered in on a wordpress documentation page, maybe I will get better answers here.

On https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/ it says

> Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost
> always be followed by a call to exit;

I don't quite understand what will really happen here if `exit` is omitted here.

PHP's [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) says `exit` is to "terminate the current script". So I assume if `wp_redirect` is called in `function.php`, the `exit` following it would stop the rest part of `function.php` from running, am I right? But why would I want that?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `wp_redirect` it sends redirect HTTP headers, and that's all the browser needs to redirect, there is no reason to continue executing code. So you must exit. `wp_redirect` will not do it for you, and PHP won't do it for you if you send the http header to redirect.

If you do not `exit`, WordPress will continue to run the rest of the page generation sequence, loading all the code, which may confuse the browser, or lead to generating HTML the browser has no interest in, as well as wasting server resources.

After all why would you continue loading the page if the server has told you to go to a new location?

But more importantly, why would PHP or WordPress do the exiting for you? What if you needed to do cleanup? Or log that you had redirected the user? Exiting is your responsibility, WordPress and PHP won't do it for you, because that would be problematic.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought when I do wp_redirect a.k.a telling the server to send new http header to my browser, then the rest of the code won't get executed at all, hence adding an `exit` is unnecessary. What did I misunderstand?

Comment: there is nothing to tell the server to stop executing the code, that's your responsibility, you have to call `exit` yourself, ***like all the docs say, it is absolutely necessary***

Comment: @shenkwen does this answer your question? If so can you mark it as the accepted answer, if not can you clarify why?

Comment: Ok but why this work is not done in the wp_redirect function ? Are there any case of having to do things after the redirect, but before the exit ?

Comment: sometimes it's useful to tell the browser to redirect then do some work instead of making it wait, that could be because you're implementing authentication and need to do additional steps such as closing connections, writing to audit logs, etc. Maybe you want to send additional headers e.g. for debugging purposes, or to log to a file that a redirect occurred because you're diagnosing a redirects problem. Maybe the user has uploaded a file and you redirect them onwards then continue processing the file in the background? If the redirect function `exit`'d none of that would be possible

Comment: for most users though, calling `exit;` immediatley afterwards is the norm. Also note that if `wp_redirect` was changed to automatically `exit` this could break tens of  millions of website